# Feedback form not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, feedback

I am trying to build a ajax feedback form but I am having problems getting it to display. The feedback image displays but when I click it nothing happens.

My Form:

```
  <div id="feedback"> 
    <img id="feedback_link" src="images/feedback.gif" href="javascript:open('feedback_form_wrapper');" /> 

      <div id="feedback_form_wrapper" style="display:none;"> 
    <a class="close light" style="float:right;margin-right:5px;" href="javascript:open('feedback_form_wrapper');" >CLOSE</a> 
    <form id="feedback_form" action="." onsubmit="submit(); return false;"> 
      <div style="margin: 8px; width: 184px; float: left;"> 
        <select name="subject"> 
          <option value="bug">Found A Bug</option> 
          <option value="typo">Found A Typo</option> 
          <option value="other">Other</option> 
        </select> 
       Email:<br/> 
       <input type="text" class="email"  name="email" /><br/> 
      <textarea name="body" id="feedback_body" style="height: 180px; margin-top: 8px;">Enter Feedback Here.</textarea> 
    <input type="submit" class="input_submit_button" value="submit" /> 
      </div> 
    </form> 
      </div> 

  </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function open(id){
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4
            document.id.display = 'block';
        }
        else { // IE 4
            document.all.id.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}

function close(id){
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4
            document.id.display = 'none';
        }
        else { // IE 4
            document.all.id.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? And as a side note, you could shorten open() and close() to one line each using a Framework (JQuery, Prototype or MooTools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your code and found the problem, you have an img tag with a href

the href attribute is for an anchor, not an img

to make this work on an image change href to onclick

also, change the name of the open() function to something else, open is already a function in javascript.

ie.

```
<img id="feedback_link" src="images/feedback.gif" onclick="show('feedback_form_wrapper');" /> 

function show(id) { ...
```

Comment: After about 20mins of it not working I realized that open() was already used and changed it... I had just started the question on here before I realized that.